# ActiveRecord has_n association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I was wondering what the best way to model a relationship where an object is associated with exactly n objects of another class. I want to extend the has_one relationship to a specific value of n.

For example, a TopFiveMoviesList would belong to user and have exactly five movies. I would imagine that the underlying sql table would have fields like movie_id_1, movie_id_2, ... movie_id_5.

I know I could do a has_many relationship and limit the number of children at the model level, but I'd rather not have an intermediary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct would be to use a join table, but if that's not desirable `User.movie[1-5]_id` columns would fit the bill. (I think `movie1_id` fits better with Rails convention than `movie_id_1`.)

Since you tagged this Rails and ActiveRecord, I'll add some completely untested and probably somewhat wrong model code to my answer. :)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  TOP_N_MOVIES = 5
  (1..TOP_N_MOVIES).each { |n|  belongs_to "movie#{n}".to_sym, :class_name => Movie }
end
```

You could wrap that line in a macro-style method, but unless if that's a common pattern for your application, doing that will probably just make your code that harder to read with little DRY benefit.

You might also want to add validations to ensure that there are no duplicate movies on a user's list.

Associating your movie class back to your users is similar.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  (1..User::TOP_N_MOVIES).each do |n| 
    has_many "users_list_as_top_#{n}".to_sym, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "movie#{n}_id"
  end

  def users_list_as_top_anything
    ary = []
    (1..User::TOP_N_MOVIES).each {|n| ary += self.send("users_list_as_top_#{n}") }
    return ary
  end

end
```

(Of course that `users_list_as_top_anything` would probably be better written out as explicit SQL.  I'm lazy today.)

Answer (score 2):

I think implementing this model through a join model is going to be you're best bet here. It allows the `List` model to worry about List logic and the `Movie` model to worry about Movie logic. You can create a `Nomination` (name isn't the greatest, but you know what I mean) model to handle the relationship between movies and lists, and when there's a limit of 5, you could just limit the number of nominations you pull back.

There are a few reasons I think this approach is better.

First, assuming you want to be able to traverse the relationships both ways (`movie.lists` and `list.movies`), the 5 column approach is going to be much messier.

While it'd be so much better for ActiveRecord to support `has n` relationships, it doesn't, and so you'll be fighting the framework on that one. Also, the `has n` relationship seems a bit brittle to me in this situation. I haven't seen that kind of implementation pulled off in ActiveRecord, though I'd be really interested in seeing it happen. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "implement" rather than "model"? The modeling's pretty easy in UML, say, where you have a Person entity that is made up of 5 Movie entities.

But the difficulty comes when you say has_one, going to has_5.  If it's a simple scalar value, has_one is perhaps a property on the parent entity. Has_5 is probably 2 entities related to one another through an "is made up of" relationship in UML.

The main question to answer is probably, "Can you guarantee that it will always be 'Top 5'?" If yes, model it with columns, as you mentioned. If no, model it with another entity.

Another question is perhaps, "How easy will it be to refactor?" If it's simple, heck, start with 5 columns and refactor to separate entities if it ever changes.

As usual, "best" is dependent on the business and technical environment.